# localStorage getItem HTML5 game issue: cannot retrieve string/number

Tags: javascript

```
var getItem = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('clickcount'));
console.log(getItem)

if (getItem === 70) {
   console.log("e")
   monker.innerHTML = "You have reached 70"
}
```

I'm making a clicker game, and when the player reaches 70, I want text to edit. However it's not working. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. The title is a bit long and has a nonsensical "Loudy594" ending. Ideally titles are a short summary of  the question, not the first sentence of your question. Also, "it's not working" is really not enough to go on. Please explain what's not happening that you expect to happen and what's happening that you're not expecting.

Comment: String !== Number

Comment: Why are you expecting a number from a JSON object? I mean, sure it works, but you'd be better off using `Number` or `parseInt`, or even a unary plus (`+"80"`).

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to store the count? The code you've posted will only make sense if we know what you've stored.

Answer (score 1):

Try parsing clickcount as an integer not as json. The returned type from localStorage is a string. JSON.parse won't convert a numerical string to a number. It will convert a string to a string of the form '"70"'.

e.g.

```
var getItem = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem('clickcount'));

if (getItem === 70) {
  console.log("e")
  monker.innerHTML = "You have reached 70"
}
```